# Return false based on user subscription validity date?

Tags: php, datetime

I've a Scenario where admin register a user details in site with the validity End date. During login, the script should validate whether it crossed the end date or not.

I can try by using this code,

```
$val_date = date("Y/m/d");

$date1 = new DateTime($val_date);
$date2 = new DateTime("2009/06/26");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

But, how should i handle Negative dates?

I mean if scenario like this,

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2009/03/24");
$date2 = new DateTime($val_date);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

Which date i should have current date? `$date1` or `$date2`?

Comment: You can convert the both the dates into timestamp by using strtotime and then you can check with normal if condition like if($current_date_timestamp < $end_date_timestamp){ //allow to login} else { //not allow to login }. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes @ManikandanS is correct in this approach.

Comment: Actually you don't need to convert to timestamp - just check the condition `$date1 < $date2` and depending on the rest would depend on the scenario...

Comment: @Moby04 $date1 and $date2 are string and their comparison can lead to unwanted results. Best way is to use strtotime to convert strings to unix timestamp. Then you can check the two numeric values without any issue

Comment: @LelioFaieta No, they are not strings - they are instances of DateTime class so simple comparison operator works fine. You can easily check it by trying simple `echo $date1` (you'll get `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR : type 4096 -- Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string -- at line #`)

Comment: You are right. I misread your comment. :)

Comment: @ManikandanS thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to set today as a date before comparison with:

```
$val_date = date("Y/m/d");
```

Just do:
    $today = strtotime(date("Y/m/d");
    $exp_date = strtotime(date("2009/06/26"));

```
if($today<$exp_date){
    echo 'Login has not expired yet';
}else{
    echo 'Login has expired and you cannot enter anymore';
}
```

strtotime convert a date (accepts a very wide option of formats) to an unix timestamp. Unix timestamp are counted as number of seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)
This means that for example as I write the unix timestamp will be '1441119516'.
It will be easy then to run any comparison or calculation like adding or removing days/hours. For example if you need to add one hour you just need to do:

```
$today+3600;
```

that is adding 60*60 seconds to the previous timestamp.